# Database nodes vs compute nodes (ESQL) in IIB, which performs better?

Tags: esb, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I understand that the Database nodes in IBM Integration Bus (IIB) toolkit are relatively new, how do they compare to using ESQL in regards to performance? and why would you choose to use one over the other?

Answer (score 2):

If you will not change the message the best option is the ***DatabaseNode*** because it works with the read-only message. So the performance is better because it does not require a copy for the output message.